# Remove decimal points in velocity template

Tags: templates, velocity

I've written an Velocity email Template. The following Number Field is displaying with a decimal place.

Incident Level: $issue.getCustomFieldValue("customfield_11513") is showing to one decimal place e.g. 4.0

How can I format this number to remove the decimal place. e.g. Just 4 instead of 4.0?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Thanks

Santosh

Comment: Please I need the solution asap. Its very urgent, can someone please answer to this. $number.integer($myNumber) is making 13,655.44 to 0. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you always want an integer, you can use [the standard Java method for transforming any Number to its integer value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#intValue%28%29):

```
$issue.getCustomFieldValue("customfield_11513").intValue()
```